# Running python script from kubernetes with input args

Tags: bash, python-2.7, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run a python script from kubernetes with input args (using import argsparse on python), the python script running fine without any input args on kubernetes, also the following command `python python_script.py -e $(date -d '2020/08/23') -d 7 -m` runs with no issues on the docker image.

I'm trying to build my values.yaml file so kubernetes could run it as well, with no success until now.

My values.yaml file (only relevant part to the script):

```
- name: python-script
  command: ["python"]
  args:
    - "python_script.py"
    - "-e $(date -d '2020/08/23')"
    - "-d 7"
    - "-m"
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 50m
      memory: 512Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 50m
      memory: 512Mi
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  restartPolicy: Never
```

**Output when running on kubernetes** : `python_script.py: error argument -e/--end_date: Not a valid date: ' $(date -d "2020/08/23")'.`

It's like the kubernetes doesn't even parse the bash command `$(date -d "2020/08/23")` into a valid date for some reason, while the docker image there's no issues with it.

I tried to add another command of `["bash"]` after the python file and add the args there but still getting error.

Any ideas? Any help will be really appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run with command `python`, then `shell` is not invoked.

So try:

```yaml
- name: python-script
  command: ["/bin/sh"]
  args:
    - -c
    - >-
        python python_script.py
        -e $(date -d '2020/08/23')
        -d 7
        -m
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 50m
      memory: 512Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 50m
      memory: 512Mi
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: The entire command `python python_script.py ...` needs to be inside a single `args:` line, but probably separate from the `-c`.

Comment: Worked! with @DavidMaze fix Victor if you can please edit the answer for future people coming accord this thanks to you both! :)

Comment: @VictorWong what does '->' under '-c' in args do?

Comment: @2bon2b you can read more about that in https://yaml-multiline.info/

Comment: two years later and you still nailed it